# Service returning empty before the http call gets complete in angular 2

Tags: angular

When I called my service it is returning some thing like this

```
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
```

But I want only the response data which I put in my code.

My service,

```
public  getAll() {
       var headers = new Headers();
       headers.append('Content-Type','application/json')
       headers.append('Authorization',this.token);
       return this.http.get(this.config.serverUrl+'user/'+this.userJson.user.id,{headers:headers})
        .map((response: Response) => {  return response.json().results; 

       });
}
```

My component,

```
constructor(private _UsersService:UsersService) { 
    this.data = _UsersService.getAll();
    console.log(this.data)
}
```

Comment: You need to subscribe to the observable. Or use the async pipe in your template. Read some documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html#!#observables, http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html

Comment: Hi Nizet why do I need Hero.ts where I declare all of my db field values?

Comment: You don't. I just linked to a page explaining the principle of observables.

Answer (score 3):

`this.data` is an Observable when you assign the response like that, if you want the values, you need to subscribe:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this._UsersService.getAll()
    .subscribe(data => {
       this.data = data;
  })
}
```

Notice that I make the call in `OnInit`, I'd say that would be the preferred way.

Comment: Did this help you? If so, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey tick under the voting of this answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235 :)